# How to filter and sort dictionary (Map) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sorting, dictionary, filter

I am trying to filter and sort dictionary (map) in Kotlin: by key = shouldShow. Is shouldShow = true, sort these objects by key = displayOrder in descending order and get string list with state names. Is it possible to do it and how? Because I am trying and nothing works.
Thanks in advance.

Map:
[{shouldShow=true, displayOrder=2, state=Alaska}, {shouldShow=false, displayOrder=3, state=Texas}, {shouldShow=true, displayOrder=1, state=Arizona}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val list = listOf(
  mapOf("shouldShow" to true, "displayOrder" to 2, "state" to "Alaska"),
  mapOf("shouldShow" to false, "displayOrder" to 3, "state" to "Texas"),
  mapOf("shouldShow" to true, "displayOrder" to 1, "state" to "Arizona")
)

val stateNames = list
  .filter { it["shouldShow"] == true }
  .sortedByDescending { it["displayOrder"] as Int }
  .map { it["state"] as String }

println(stateNames)   // [Alaska, Arizona]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't manually create list. I have this Map<*,*>:  [{shouldShow=true, displayOrder=2, state=Alaska}, {shouldShow=false, displayOrder=3, state=Texas}, {shouldShow=true, displayOrder=1, state=Arizona}] and I have to get stateNames under special conditions. Under other conditions, the answer would suit me. Thanks

Comment: The manual list is an example for testing purposes, because you did not post one, which YOU should have done.

Comment: And I interpreted your string as a List of Maps, since [] in Kotlin printouts stands for List and {} stands for Map. Another indication: there are no keys on the top level, so it cannot be a Map of Maps.

Comment: Okay, I have [{shouldShow=true, displayOrder=2, state=Alaska}, {shouldShow=false, displayOrder=3, state=Texas}, {shouldShow=true, displayOrder=1, state=Arizona}]  as List<*>. How can I get stateNames without manually creating new list? for example it["shouldShow"] and other [] are highlighted in red

Comment: Again: my list is just an example list. Apply the code above starting with the line "val stateNames = list" to your list by replacing the word "list" with the name of your variable holding your list.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did this and it is not working.  No get method providing array access

Comment: The need to do `as Int` and `as String` (and the subsequent risk of them failing) is one of the code smells associated with using maps when instances of an appropriate class would be better. Ditto having to use `["…"]` lookups (and the risk of _those_ failing). Ditto the `== true`.

Comment: @gidds: Yes, I would also vote for a data class here.

Comment: @lukas.j It used to be [said](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html) that a determined programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language… The modern equivalent seems to be trying to write Javascript programs in any language! I guess if you're coming from dynamic/scripting languages, it could be hard to get used to thinking in objects. (But it's well worth the effort, of course.)

Comment: @lukas.j I modified a bit and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Objective24: Glad to hear that it work out.